# How can I find obb folder in a rooted device to copy a game's sd data files and play game?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-management

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2. Before I rooted my phone and I played games like Modern Combat 4, Virtue Tennis, Need for Speed Most Wanted and The Dark Knight Rises. These are games' sd data, I copied in obb folder.

Now I've rooted my phone and I want to install those games but I cant find obb folder in my device. Where do I copy the game's sd data? Can I play these kind of games in a rooted device?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a backup tool by Koushik Dutta (aka Koush) : [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en)

Using this you can backup complete app including data and restore it back. Just backup on your device, copy the files to your other device and restore it back.

I've tested it personally and it works flawlessly on non rooted devices.

Try this and let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you didn't find it, that shouldn't be a problem. Just create a new folder. Name it `OBB`, and copy your game content in there.

Answer (score -1):

Create that `obb` folder in `Android` folder.